# Adding vertical line on xAxis in HighStock

Tags: plot, line, highcharts

I know I can plot horizontal lines on yAxis using plotLines, but how about vertical lines on xAxis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the same way as in the yAxis, you need to use plotLines

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines

Highstock: http://jsfiddle.net/kZkWZ/

```
value: Date.UTC(2011,3,1),
```

Value should be js timestamp, because xAxis has datetime type.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This works well on HighCharts, but doesn't seem to work on HighStock.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, Sebastian. This is exactly what I need. I can't vote your answer up, because it requires 15 reputation:/